# How to remove this shower handle?

Tags: bathroom, shower, faucet, screws

I am having a hard time trying to remove this shower handle. I am not sure what model it is (although it looks similar to some Kohler designs I saw on their website).

There is a hole under the handle but none of my allen keys or screwdrivers seem to be working in unscrewing this set screw. I tried wd40 as well, but to no avail. I am starting to wonder whether there is one at all, but if there wasn't why would there be a hole?

I tried removing the large screws holding the square to the wall, in case it was just one big piece, but the square seems to be a separate part from the handle itself.

FYI

- I would like to remove it in order to adjust the rotational limit stop: the water coming out is either cold or scalding hot.

[image: Shower handle]

**EDIT** Adding a pic, not the best shot, sorry but I don't have a torch and had to rely on flash.

**EDIT** Managed to get it off and fix the issue. What did it was a torx key T10. Had to buy a set, but was worth it. Thanks so much for your help!

[image: hole2]

Comment: Can you get a good look inside the hole?  It should be a hex screw head of some sort.  Maybe it is caked with soap and oils?

Comment: It may also be the case of metric vs non-metric hex screws.  pro-tip: if you can't look up into the hole, your phone camera might be able to.

Comment: @wallyk thanks, here's a pic. I doubt it's caked, as it's pretty new and was barely used.

Comment: It looks like a hex hole.  What do you have for hex drivers?  Metric?  English?   er.... Did one come with the handle?

Comment: cool, don't have any hex driver. Will a hardware store be able to suggest the appropriate one with those pics? I'll try to take measurements too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely a "hex/Allen/socket" head set screw, you can plainly see the hex in your picture if you look close. I think you may have been using too small a key:

[image]

Comment: Great. Managed to get it off and fix the issue. What did it was a torx key T10. Had to buy a set, but was worth it. Thanks so much for your help!